# Alert not displaying after page refresh/reload (Angular v10)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am developing an Angular single page app, where when the user clicks a button, the page is refreshed and a message is displayed.

(TYPESCRIPT)

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

export class newComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  showAlertMessage = false;

  buttonClicked(dataElement: DataModel): void {
    this.restService.postAction(dataElement, 'a new record is being inserted').subscribe();
    window.location.reload();
    this.showAlertMessage = true;
  }
```

(HTML)

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Header </th>
    <td mat-icon *matCellDef="let element">
      <button (click)="buttonClicked(element)">No Data To Report</button>
    </td>
</table>

  <div class="alert alert-primary" *ngIf="showAlertMessage" role="alert">
    This is a primary alert—check it out!
  </div>
```

The problem I am having is when the user clicks, the alert message briefly shows, then disappears while the page is refreshed. How do I reload the page, then display the message? Currently the message doesn't show after window.location.reload() occurs in the buttonClicked() method.

Comment: After reloading the page, all context in memory is lost. To solve this problem you must store data in local storage or cookie or another method such as passing a value as a parameter in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reloading the page re-initialises the application which means that your `showAlertMessage = false;` is being executed again once the component loads.

A simple way to get the behaviour you want is to use url params. On button click you modify the path you're on to include something like `?showAlertMessage=true` so that on 2nd load the initial state differs. ([example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rcgkwi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts))

Alternative options to it are as Andre mentioned, using the localstorage or some other method of persisting state outside of the app scope.

You might also want to consider if reloading is the right solution here since re-initialising the whole application takes time and goes a bit against the whole idea of a SPA.

Comment: I agree, reloading the whole page is not ideal. It just works for what I'm doing, as the user action is affecting the backend data (which is what I'm displaying on the UI)

Comment: I was wondering if you could take a look at another post, where I am trying to do the same thing but pass a string value as the URL parameter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68930335/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-a-button-alert-angular-v10/68930979#68930979