# How to pass multiple parameters to a button alert (Angular v10)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

(Typescript)

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

export class newComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  showAlert = false;
  firstName = '';

  constructor() {
    this.url = window.location.href;
    this.showAlert = new URL(this.url).searchParams.get('showAlert') === 'true';
    //this.firstName = new URL(this.url).searchParams.get('firstName');
  }

  buttonClicked(dataElement: DataModel): void {
    window.location.href = this.url + '?showAlert=true' + '&firstName=' + dataModel.firstName;
  }

  closeAlert(): void {
    this.showAlert=false;
    this.alert.nativeElement.classList.remove('show');
  }
```

(HTML)

```
  <div *ngIf="showAlert" #alert class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeAlert()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    {{firstName}} has made a selection
  </div>

<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Header </th>
    <td mat-icon *matCellDef="let element">
      <button (click)="buttonClicked(element)">Make a Selection</button>
    </td>
</table>
```

The button alert works and is displayed on the UI when I make the selection. However, I only see ' has made a selection' and don't see the firstName displaying.

What happens is I can seen the first name and showAlert equal to true in the url when I click the button, but the firstName parameter is not displaying in the button alert HTML. I am getting the value to show in the URL so I don't think it's an issue with the dataModel getting the value. I think the issue is in the constructor, where I have a commented line to try and get it using searchParams.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot to set the `firstName` attribute in your `buttonClicked` method:

```js
buttonClicked(dataElement: DataModel): void {
  this.firstName = dataElement.firstName;
  window.location.href = this.url + '?showAlert=true' + '&firstName=' + dataModel.firstName;
}
```

Without this change, `firstName` would always be equal to its default value, which is am empty string in your case. This is why you only see ' has made a selection' displayed in your alert.